# Why In Delphi 5 showing Dsgnintf.dcu not found error

Tags: delphi

hi I tried one component code in Delphi 5. and got Error DsgnIntf.Dcu not found.

Actually I was transferring my Code from Delphi 5 to Delphi XE5. In Delphi XE5 
while running I got error DesignIntf.dcu not found .

I tried all way replace DesignIntF, Design Editor and all.

I got response that 'Delphi after Delphi 6 not redistributed this Designtime code'.

then at last I Tried it on Delphi 5 for testing . in that version Dsgnintf.dcu 
should not come.

I think Not Redistribution but another problem in it. can get direction regards this ?

thanks
abhishek mestri

Comment: Borland stopped supplying the source of DsgnIntf to enforce the separation between code that's intended to execute in a package in the IDE (e.g. design-time aspects of components) and to execute in a Delphi-compiled application.  By the sound of it, you have a home-rolled or 3rd party package that doesn't observe that distinction.  If you separate out the design-time part of the code from the runtime part into separate units, and use only the runtime one in your application, the problem compiling it should go away. Does that answer your q?

Comment: In what way is this question different from the one you asked a couple of days ago?

Answer (score 0):

DsgnIntf.Dcu is a part of ToolsAPI. Now in newer versions of Delphi this file has been replaced by DesignIntf.pas.

Based on information on site below replacing references from DsgnIntf to DesignIntf solves the problem most of the times. But I would not count on this as there were lots of changes from Delphi 5 to Delphi XE5. Here is the link to the site:

http://www.delphifaq.com/faq/delphi/vcl/f266.shtml

EDIT: ToolsAPI by default wasn't available in Personal editions of Delphi. This unfortunately mean that for those of you who own Personal edition of Delphi my answer won't help.

Newer versions of Delphi use Open Tools API which are available in all Delphi editions so there is no more restriction for you to own athleast Proffesional Edition to use it. I'm not sure in which Delphi version was this change made.

Comment: If the OP is asking about compiling an application, rather than a package to install in the IDE, the DsgnIntf to DesignIntf substitution will not help, only separating the code out into r/time and design-time units will.  I'm saying that not to criticise your answer but in the hope that the OP realises what the problem is.

Comment: No I agree with your answer but, why that code show same error in delphi 5 where i should not come and it has already install in some of my colleague  Delphi 5? thats the question

Comment: ToolsAPI library wasn't available in Personal editions only in Professional and above. So if you are trying to use/compile this on personal Edition I'm afraid it won't work.